# "background-attachment: fixed" somehow is working on mobile device

Tags: css, background, background-image, background-attachment

I know it's a topic that has been answered several times, but I'm playing with css "background-attachment:fixed" property, and I wanted to make it work on mobile devices.

The answer is: it's not possible, because it is forced to "scroll" for performence reasons.
Knowing that, I still tried, and I found these examples on w3schools : [example 1](https://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_js_background-attachment), [example 2](https://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_background-attachment).

These two examples both work on my chrome mobile browser (running on Android 7.0). No matter how hard I try, I can't reproduce this behaviour.

I inspected the code and it seems based solely on background-attachment to work.

How is it possible, and how can I reproduce this?

Comment: show us your *hard* try then

Comment: Well all my tries are on my local website I'm building. I just wrote a codepen to begin with, that shows that on mobile, the property is disabled. I just copied / pasted the w3schools second example, and of course it does not work outside their website. Here is [the codepen](https://codepen.io/TheMadOcarina/pen/NBmqjJ)